# How to fix a package from Sublime Text that doesn't read its color scheme?

Tags: xml, package, yaml, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

```
note
  > note.sublime-color-scheme
  > note.sublime-syntax
  > note.tmTheme
  > sample.note
```

This is how my package structure called `note` looks like. I created and registered my `custom scope` name called ***my.own.scope*** onto a specific text pattern from `.sublime-syntax` file and it works just fine without any of the problem in my `sample.note` file.

Now, I'm trying to style the text what it is hooked by ***my.own.scope*** using `.sublime-color-scheme` file, but ST doesn't style the text at all.

How can I solve this error? I created a new `.tmTheme` file to fix this problem, but nothing happened either.

Codes from `.sublime-syntax`;

```
%YAML 1.2
---
file_extensions:
  - note
scope: text.plain.note

contexts:
  main:
    - match: '^-\s{1,}\w+'
      scope: my.own.scope
```

Codes from `.sublime-color-scheme`;

```
{
    "name": "Note",
    "variables": {
        "black": "hsl(0, 0%, 0%)",
    },
    "globals": {
        "foreground": "",
        "background": "",
        "accent": "",
        "selection": "",
    },
    "rules": [
        {
            "name": "myOwnScope",
            "scope": "my.own.scope",
            "foreground": "var(black)",
        }
    ]
}
```

Codes from `.tmTheme` file;

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>note</string>
    <key>scopeName</key>
    <string>source.base_scope</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>myOwnScope</string>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>my.own.scope</string>
            <key>settings</key>

            <dict>
                <key>foreground</key>
                <string>#000000</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>41f141d6-0432-43ef-87d0-d509ac95f110</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It looks like your `sublime-color-scheme` is trying to be a complete color scheme on its own and not an addition to an existing color scheme; your color scheme won't be used unless you alter your settings in Sublime to tell it to use that one (but you probably don't want to because it only has one scope rule in it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `tmTheme` and `sublime-color-scheme` are treated identically once loaded, so in this case what works in one will work in the other as well. Files of both types with the same name will be merged together into one on load. so having a file with the same name in both types will likely cause you confusion and heartache in the future; you should pick one and delete the other. The general advice is to not use `tmTheme` unless you have a compelling reason to do so, because `sublime-color-scheme` has more features (e.g. variables).

The larger issue though, is that based on your question you might be thinking that because the syntax is named `note.sublime-syntax`, that you need to create a `note.sublime-color-scheme` in order to set up the colors for it, but that's not how that works.

The color scheme that Sublime uses is controlled by the `color_scheme` setting in your `Preferences.sublime-settings`; so to activate your color scheme you would need to edit your preferences and set `color_scheme` to `note.sublime-color-scheme`, for example.

Likely you don't want to do that though. Your example above contains only a single color rule that will make that text black. When a color scheme is empty, the defaults are a `white` background and `black` text, so if that color scheme was in fact active, what you would see is a white window with all text being black by default, and the text matched by your scope would similarly be black, so you would not be able to notice any difference.

In all likelihood, what you want to do here is choose `UI: Customize Color Scheme` from the Command Palette or `Preferences > Customize Color Scheme` from the menu, and then add the single `rule` entry you have above into the `rule` section of the file that will open in the right hand pane.

Doing so will augment your existing color scheme to have the extra rule that colorizes the scope you've added to your sample syntax.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I couldn't check the website in last 2 weeks because I was quite busy that time. Always huge thanks to you for giving me the detailed answers. Bless you.